# Debugging vtable workings

Tags: c#, debugging, vtable

```
    internal class SchoolCalendar
    {
        public void GetSchoolYear()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base GetSchoolYear called from: " + this);
            LeapYear();
        }

        public virtual void LeapYear()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base Leap Year");
        }
    }

    internal class DerivedSchoolCalendar : SchoolCalendar
    {
        public override void LeapYear()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Derived Leap Year");
        }
    }


    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SchoolCalendar bsy = new DerivedSchoolCalendar();
            bsy.GetSchoolYear();
        }
    }
```

In the code above, the base class calls a base class method, and said method calls a virtual method.

I'm trying to figure out in more detail how a vtable works. Especially the order of things. I was taught that in this code the vtable for the derived class is invoked. I thought that the vtable for the base class was invoked first and only then a pointer to a second vtable is invoked.

I would like to know more and better about order of it's workings inside whatever vtable. Is there a way to debug having a mind I just want to follow vtable access? (note, I know nothing about reflection for example, be gentle please).

Comment: "vtable" is a C++ word, the rough C# equivalent is the "methodtable".  Very rough, it is much more sophisticated and doesn't much operate like a vtable.  And requires a special debugger to look at it, the SOS extension for WinDbg.  Its !dumpmt command shows the table.  Be sure to read up on the internals to make sense of what it shows, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/may/net-framework-internals-how-the-clr-creates-runtime-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User @HansPassant placed a comment which I consider to be the answer. The SOS extension for WinDbg in combination with the dumpmt command will provide data to figure out my own question.